# How to call fluent wait function from another class to a test case in selenium webdriver?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have created a new class called "FluentWaitClass" and added fluent wait like below: And I want to use this wait functionality to check whether my login page has loaded in one of my below test case "TC_LoginTest_001.java". Can anyone please help letting me know how to do that ?

````
package com.internetBanking.utilities;

import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Wait;

import com.google.common.base.Function;

public class FluentWaitClass {
    
        WebDriver driver;
    
    // Waiting 30 seconds for an element to be present on the page, checking
       // for its presence once every 5 seconds.
       @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
           .withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
           .pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
           .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

       WebElement foo = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() 
       {
         public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
           return driver.findElement(By.id("foo"));
         }
       });
}

**TC_LoginTest_001.java**

package com.internetBanking.testCases;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import com.internetBanking.pageObjects.LoginPage;
import com.internetBanking.utilities.*;

public class TC_LoginTest_001 extends BaseClass {
    
    @Test
    public void LoginTest() {
                
        driver.get(baseURL);
        logger.info("URL is opened");
        
        FluentWaitClass fluentwait = new FluentWaitClass();
        
        LoginPage loginPage = new LoginPage(driver);
        
        loginPage.setUsrname(username);
        logger.info("Username is entered");
        
        
        
        loginPage.setPwd(password);
        logger.info("Password is entered");
        
        loginPage.login();                                         
        logger.info("Login button is clicked");
        
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is the implementation:**

```
// Waiting 30 seconds for an element to be present on the page, checking
       // for its presence once every 5 seconds.
       @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
           .withTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
           .pollingEvery(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
           .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
```

**This is usage:**

```
 WebElement foo = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() 
       {
         public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
           return driver.findElement(By.id("foo"));
         }
       });
```

you just copy pasted the code from the example and added it in the FluentWaitClass  ,

In your code just return "wait" from that class and use it in your test

### But if you are going to just ignore nosuchelement then you can use normal wait , don't make it fancy with fluent wait

```
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait((WebDriver) driver, Duration.ofSeconds(20));
    WebElement element = wait.until(
            ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated((By.id("someid"))));
```

---

Comment: Thanks @PDHide. I used the normal wait and it worked. Can I define this normal wait in another separate class and implement this wait in my test cases wherever necessary ?

Comment: yes you can you can return wait using a method or define method as public variable in base class  and access it from test class

Comment: Please accept the answer by clicking the tick sgin